# Description of the flag Rāma carried in His battle against Rāvaṇa

Tags: rama, skanda-purana

As far as I know, there are no explicit and detailed descriptions of the flag Rāma carried in His battle against Rāvaṇa present in the Rāmāyaṇa.

However, elaborate descriptions of the flag are said to be present in both the Skandapurāṇa and Kūrmapurāṇa.

Can somebody provide me with the relevant references from these texts?